# SonarQube VSTS Marketplace Extension

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube

I downloaded the extension from
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarqube#review-details,
for TFS 2015 on premise, installed it in my collection and created and end point. Then I configured 2 steps as indicated before and after my build, I am getting the following error

> ### [error]The MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner executable could not be found. Check that the build definition includes a SonarQube Pre-Build step

My sonar server Version is 5.6.3 running on Linux fedora. Do I need to install any other tools? I understand that The SonarQube Extension embeds its own version of the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild. The first step before the build executes correctly, the build succeed but the end step fails.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Could you please post here the build log so that we can investigate? Thanks.

Comment: What're detail build steps and log? Can you analysis the project via command on build agent server?  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/09/28/quickstart-analyzing-net-projects-with-sonarqube-msbuild-or-visual-studio-online-and-third-party-analyzers-stylecop-resharper/

Comment: I can post the log as it longer longer to what is allowed but just noticed the following the log

Comment: Starting task: Prepare the SonarQube ..
Executing the powershell script: Users\.....\2.0.0\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2
Default properties file was found at C:\Users\...\SonarQubeScannerMsBuildBegin\2.0.0\SonarQubeScannerMsBuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis...from C:\Users\\BuildAgt\tasks\SonarQubeScannerMsBuildBegin\2.0.0\SonarQubeScannerMsBuild\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started
Preparing ....
[error]
[error]Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\BuildQgent-2K15\_work\4\.sonarqube\bin' is denied

Comment: I can share the full log if you need

Comment: You can share the log file on the OneDrive

Comment: What's the location of your build agent? Is it in the users folder? On the other hand, the error is related to C:\BuildQgent-2K15_work\4\.sonarqube\bin path, try to delete the files in  C:\BuildQgent-2K15_work\4 folder and try again.